# comparing date.toUTCString() using greater than ( > ) always returns false whether the other date is older or younger

Tags: javascript, date, compare, utc

I am trying to get data less than 2 days old from my database using a timestamp but when trying to compare the two dates, the date that is 2 days ago always returns false whether it is being compared to an older date or a younger date.

```js
let twoDaysAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
let yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
let fiveDaysAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

console.log(twoDaysAgo.toUTCString() > yesterday.toUTCString()); // returns false
console.log(twoDaysAgo.toUTCString() > fiveDaysAgo.toUTCString()); // also returns false
console.log(twoDaysAgo.toUTCString() < yesterday.toUTCString()); // of course returns true instead
```

Weird thing is that this code was working just fine a couple days ago, don't know what happened between now and then.

Answer (score 3):

Since both the operands of the comparison operators are strings, you are doing a lexicographic comparison.

The `toUTCString` method of a Date instance returns a string that starts with a three-letter day of the week (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri or Sat).

Suppose that today was a Monday. Then:

- `yesterday` would be a Sunday, so `yesterday.toUTCString()` would start with `"Sun"`.
- `twoDaysAgo` would be a Saturday, so `twoDaysAgo.toUTCString()` would start with `"Sat"`.
- `fiveDaysAgo` would be a Wednesday, so `fiveDaysAgo.toUTCString()` would start with `"Wed"`.

In this case the results of `toUTCString` happen to have the same order as the natural ordering of the dates themselves (as `"Wed" < "Sat" < "Sun"` in lexicographic order), so it is a coincidence that the results of the comparisons are correct.

Now suppose that today was a Tuesday instead and repeat the same argument. You will find the cause of the "weird" results you are getting.

To compare dates correctly you should use `getTime`:

```js
twoDaysAgo.getTime() > yesterday.getTime(); // returns false
twoDaysAgo.getTime() > fiveDaysAgo.getTime(); // returns true
twoDaysAgo.getTime() < yesterday.getTime(); // returns true
```

Comment: I think OP should just be comparing the Date objects themselves instead of the human-readable string version. You could use `Date.prototype.getTime()`, but the `<` and `>` already use the `valueOf()` function, so it's really no difference.

Comment: So there is no way of comparing the UTC string itself? That's a shame lol, that's how I stored the timestamp in my psql database so I was trying to get data by comparing the strings.